# How to compare an array with another array in Assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, compare, x86-16

I was trying to compare array1 with array2. Here is a part of my code, but it wont work.

```
mov si, 00
mov di, 00    

Compare:
cmp array1[si], array2[di]
je checking
jmp compare
```

Im doing an assembly program that will ask the user to input string. the first string is labeled as an input. 2nd string is the old character sequence.
3rd string is the new replaced character sequence.

---

Sample:

Input: hatatat

Old String: at

Replace with: eh

OUTPUT: heheheh

---

Comment: You can't have two memory operands with `cmp`. Load one of the characters into a register first, or use the `cmps` instruction. Also, you need to increase `si` and `di` after each pair of characters that you've compared, and have some sort of check to see if you've moved past the end of either array.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `cmp` as most x86 instructions can't process two memory locations at once. You need to load one of the arguments in a register. For example:

```
mov   al, [Array1+si]
cmp   al, [Array2+di]
```

Perhaps, there is a group of instructions that **can** process two memory arguments simultaneously - the string instructions as `lods, stos, cmps, movs, ...`
These instructions always work with memory pointer in [si] and/or [di] (esi and edi in 32bit mode) and does not accept constant offset.

```
mov   si, Array1
mov   di, Array2
cld              

cmpsb  ; compares two bytes - from [si] and [di] and then increments si and di by 1
```

Please, read the instructions reference manual for more detailed description.

**Note**: As long as you didn't provide information about preferred assembly syntax, I am using FASM syntax in the examples. If you are using another assembler, you probably should edit the code in accordance with its syntax.

Comment: Wouldn’t you either compare `Array1+si` (loaded into `al` and `Array2+s1`, then `inc si`? Or else compare [si] to [di] and `inc` both?

Comment: @Davislor Yes, in this case using one of the registers is better, but the OP use di and si and I wanted to make the code as close to his code as possible.